# How to retrieve post data, validate it in controller and save it in database using GORM in Micronaut?

Tags: groovy, grails-orm, micronaut

I come from Grails background and have recently started a project in Micronaut using GORM.

I tried to find required information in documentation but its not clear how we retrieve post data in controller, validate it similar to Command Objects offered in Grails and save it into database using interface service provided in documentation

PS : I know I can map every field to action argument in controller, and also declare a interface method specifying each argument as property but that does not seems right thing to do as my domain class has so many properties.
Making the action @Transactional or any method would work for saving data as far as I know but I want to know the proper way in Micronaut.

My requirement is simple, save post data in database using GORM in Micronaut.

Comment: Did you look at [Handling Form Data](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#formData)?  I have not tried this yet, but it is something I will need to do soon.  I wonder if the Domain object can be used as the @Body argument.  You will probably have to do the find() and update in your code.

Comment: I am looking into that, will let you know if that works.

Comment: Damm, people downvote questions without even telling the reason for downvote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would look back at the documentation, sections 6.4 to 6.11:
    https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#binding

https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#datavalidation
    http://hibernate.org/validator/

Micronaut is very annotation based, unlike Grails which uses convention over configuration. However in Grails 4, Micronaut will toke over the application context, giving you some of the benefits of Micronaut, but still maintaining the convention over configuration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, indeed above sections cover all about request binding and validation.